# How does the function from Urysohn's lemma look like?

Tags: general-topology

I recently studied about Urysohn's lemma, and I wonder how does the function obtained by it, looks like, particularly, what iS. So suppose $C, D$ are closed sets in topological space $X$ which is T4, and $f$ is the function I get from Urysohn's lemma, where for each $x$ in $C$, $f(x) = 1$, and for each $y$ in $D$, $f(x) = 0$, are there other $x$ in $X$ for which $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = 1$ and are not in $C$ or $D$? in other words, is the inverse image of $1$ equal to $C$ and the inverse image of $0$ is $D$? Is it true only for one of the cases?

Comment: What happened when you examined the proof of Urysohn's Lemma to see what information it gave you about these questions?

Comment: It was clear to me that the inverse image of 1 might be bigger than C, but for the inverse image of 0, I find it difficult to decide whether it is D or not, since you keep on taking smaller and smaller sets that contain D, so for every point outside of D there is a subset which contains it also, so I am not sure about this case

Answer (score 0):

If all you know about $X$ is that it's $T_4$, then you cannot in general arrange for the function $f$ from Urysohn's Lemma can take the values $0$ and $1$ only on the prescribed sets $C$ and $D$. For example, if $X$ is the ordinal space $\omega_1+1$ with the order topology, then every continuous real-valued function that vanishes at the "last" point $\omega_1$ must also vanish at all but countably many of the other points. (This $X$ is $T_4$ because it's a compact Hausdorff space.)

If, on the other hand, you have stronger information about $X$, then you may be able to arrange for $f$ to take the values $0$ and $1$ only on $C$ and $D$. Metrizability of $X$ is (more than) sufficient for this.